# scrollIntoView issue with iOS Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am facing some bugs when i use scrollIntoView library in my code for an iPad. It is working on other devices like android but not on iPad. Eventually, if i remove that line of code, it doesn't through any errors. I need the scrollIntoView in for the following functionality-

I have a list of attributes(lets say list of accounts), when i click on any account that specific account should move to the top of the list( should not replace the position id's. Just scroll the view to the top with selected account in first). How can i achieve this with out using scrollIntoView?

I researched a bit on this but couldnt get a solution. I tried smoothscroll with polyfill but couldnt get it work. Any suggestions out there?

I followed the below post but of no luck :
[Mobile Safari, scrollIntoView doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098593/mobile-safari-scrollintoview-doesnt-work)

Comment: did you manage to find a way to fix this ?

Comment: No i did not find a solution for this. I bipassed the check if it is an iOS