# scrollIntoView() doesn't scroll anywhere

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I can't get `Element.scrollIntoView()` to work. I have the code below. There are two locations that it should scroll to, depending on some variable. However, it doesn't scroll to either of them. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Page extends Component {
    scrollToMyRef = (id) => {
        var ref = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log("Ref1: " + ref);            // returns [object HTMLElement]
        console.log("Ref2: " + document.ref);   // returns undefined
        console.log("Id: " + id);               // returns myRef
        ref.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "start",
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.location.state) {
            if (this.props.location.state.origine) {
                this.scrollToMyRef("myRef");
            } else {
                this.scrollToMyRef("myTopRef");
                });
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                id="myTopRef"
                key="pricing"
                className="pricing"
            >
                ...
            </div>
            <section id=myRef className="section">
                ...
            </section>
            ...
        )
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to show your CSS and markup: is the element `#myRef` in an **overflowing parent**? `scrollIntoView` only works if the element itself is outside the viewport + its parent is scrollable.

Comment: In the `block` property, try specifying `nearest` instead of `start`, but there's no guarantee. I used it in a table a while ago and it works as stated by Terry: only if the element is outside the viewport.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to make a difference. It's still not scrolling.

Comment: Interestingly, if I remove `behavior: "smooth",` or set it to `auto`, my original code works. Any idea why this is? I would like to use the smooth behavior...

Comment: I've got it working now. I needed to set a time delay:
`    scrollToMyRef = (id) => {
        var ref = document.getElementById(id);
 setTimeout(function () {
        ref.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "start",
        });
  }, 100);
    };`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After setting a time delay it worked:

```
scrollToMyRef = (id) => {
      var ref = document.getElementById(id);
      setTimeout(function () {
           ref.scrollIntoView({
               behavior: "smooth",
               block: "start",
           });
      }, 100);
};
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, made me soooooo happy!!! No idea why it works, though.

Comment: Same problem as OP, but this time delay didn't solve it for me. Mine still doesn't scroll at all until I remove the behavior: smooth.

Comment: It will depend at what point you are invoking `scrollToMyRef`, but if it's after a change of state, without actually waiting for the change of state to render, then that might be the reason `setTimeout` solves your problem.

If that's the case, you can use `setTimeout(..., 0)` that is, there's no need to wait at all, just run the function on the next iteration of the event loop.

Comment: That solution did not make me happy. But it did work

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. `scrollIntoView` was working only if `behavior` was `auto`. Setting a delay fixed some cases but not all of them. In addition, Safari doesn't support smooth scrolling at all. I used [this polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seamless-scroll-polyfill#import-via-script) which works for all browsers and all cases.

You can use it in the following way:

```js
import { scrollIntoView } from "seamless-scroll-polyfill";

scrollIntoView(element, {
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start",
  },
  {
    duration: 250 // aprox. the duration that chrome uses,
  }
);
```

Comment: According to caniuse, safari should offer full support as of 16+. It's a shame this polyfill is necessary. https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollIntoView